# Filter rows by criteria and select multiple columns from a dataframe with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following dataframe subset

```
       A   B   C   D   E   Date
   R0  xy  78  io  16  73  2021-03-25
   R1  xx  27  ya  80   1  2021-04-20
   R2  xx  53  ya  27  44  2021-06-20
   R3  xx  65  io  30  84  2021-08-22
   R4  xv   9  ui  62   1  2021-08-01
```

How can I do with panda to have the following dataframe:

```
       A   B   C   Date
   R1  xx  27  ya  2021-04-20
   R2  xx  53  ya  2021-06-20
```

I was thinking of filtering columns by doing:

```
sbset = subset[['A','B','C', 'Date' ]]
```

and then filter where A = 'XX' and C = 'ya', but with a dataframe of 1 million of obs and 127 vars it takes too long, can I do both actions (filter by two or more variables and select more variables) in one step?

Another question, if the dataframe takes the dates as a string, how can I change the format to date?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `df.loc[df['A'].eq('xx')&df['C'].eq('ya') , ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Date']]`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need boolean making for this:

```
mask=(df['A']=='xx') & (df['C']=='ya')
```

Finally:-

```
result=df[mask]
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output